# Retaining dialog box until fields are validated

Tags: android

am showing a dialog as shown in the image when the fileds are validated only the dialog should be gone until it should retian..i want to send the data to the server only when the fields are validated..any help please.

[image]

```
               alertotp=new AlertDialog.Builder(Streaming_Login.this);
                LayoutInflater inflaterotp=Streaming_Login.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View layoutotp=inflaterotp.inflate(R.layout.otp, null);
                alertotp.setView(layoutotp);
                final TextView txtref=(TextView) layoutotp.findViewById(R.id.txtotpref);
                final EditText edtotp=(EditText) layoutotp.findViewById(R.id.edtotp);
                final EditText edtotppwd=(EditText) layoutotp.findViewById(R.id.edtotppwd);
                final EditText edtotpcnfrm=(EditText) layoutotp.findViewById(R.id.edtoptcnfrmpwd);
                txtref.setText("Reference number is: " +rslt);

                alertotp.setTitle("Change Password");
                //alertotp.setCancelable(false);
                alertotp.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String strotp=edtotp.getText().toString().trim();
                        String strpwd=edtotppwd.getText().toString().trim();
                        String strcnfrmpwd=edtotpcnfrm.getText().toString().trim();
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", user));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("otp", strotp));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refId", rslt));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strpwd));


                        final TextView txtot=new TextView(Streaming_Login.this);
                        txtot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                String straftrotp=txtot.getText().toString().trim();
                                System.out.println("The result after sending otp is ..." +straftrotp);
                                if(straftrotp.equals("SUCCESS"))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password has been changed succesfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        synchronized (txtot) {
                            if(user.equals("") || strotp.equals("") || rslt.equals("") || strpwd.equals(""))
                            {
                                //alertotp.setCancelable(false);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No field should be empty....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else{

                                if(strpwd.equals(strcnfrmpwd))
                                {

                                    new CustomHttpClient().executeHttpPost(httpUrlchngpwd, postParameters, txtot);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //alertotp.setCancelable(false);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The password and confirm password are not same please try again....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
                alertotp.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the value of a text field and compare to see if it is empty

```
String str = edtotp.getText().toString();
if( str.length() !=0 ){ //or str.isEmpty() from API 9
//the field has text
} else {
//the field is empty
}
```

You can also use to validate functions like

```
str.contains("v"); //for specific characters
str.endsWith("value"); //the prefix of the string
str.startsWith("value"); //the end of it
str.equals("Value"); //is it equal to the needed value
str.equalsIgnoreCase("Value"); //same, just ignores the case of letters
```

Also you can convert, format, concatenate, trim, substring, etc.
useful links

[String class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

[Integer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html)

[Pattern class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)